# Qt c++ find usages using connect-statements

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, mouse, right-click

I define a signal-slot-connection in *userinterface* like that :

```
connect(  ui.Diagram  , SIGNAL( sendChartImportVariablesToUI( QList <QVariant>  &)  ),
          this  ,SLOT (getVariablesFromChartImport( QList <QVariant>  &))) ;
```

Now when I mark *sendChartImportVariablesToUI* in *userinterface* ( which is a signal defined in another class) and use **rightMouseclick-> Find Usages**  Qt won' t show me the usages of *sendChartImportVariablesToUI*  in that other class. It even won`t show me the use in the Connect-statement in User interface.

Is there a command like **rightMouseclick-> Find Usages in ALL CLASSES** that would show me the use in **all** the classes of my project?

Comment: what IDE are you using? QtCreator?

Comment: yes, it`s QtCreator 2.8.1 with Qt 4.8.4

Comment: as your question is about the IDE you should add that to the question

Comment: @nwp You're right, thanks for your feedback. he should switch to Qt 5 or let say that not possible to find usage.

Comment: I hope you have a really good reason for wasting productivity by using [ancient technology](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/08/28/qt-creator-2-8-1-installer-framework-1-4-0-released/). If you can reconsider your options you should probably do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Qt bug and you can see it in bug report in qt website:

> There is a problem with "find usage". It does not find usage of
>   signals/slots in other classes.

Report links:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13929?jql=text%20~%20%22find%20usage%20signal%20slot%22

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1863

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13601

**Solution:** Use new version [of Qt Creator](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/) and [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) :

```
connect(sender, &Sender::valueChanged,receiver, &Receiver::updateValue);
```

With this connection you can find usage and Qt will find connection line.

[image: sample code image]